# Automatically close Output window in vsc running salesforce CLI

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, ide, vs-code

I have switched from Sublime to VSCode.  I have found ways to make most of VSCode work the way I want.  The main thing I wish I could do is when I deploy to the org if it is successful I would like the Output window and SFDX notice to automatically close.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but I don't seem to have enough reputation to comment that I would really love this feature to be included.

And if the error detection is difficult to do in a timely manner, please provide a settings flag to just not open the output window and or show the toast popup message that the operation is running and only show a toast popup on completion.

Comment: This is my biggest annoyance.  You would think it wouldn't be that big of a deal but I end up leaving it open so loose 3 inches of screen